# Excel to XML Namespace Prefix Customization

Tags: xml, excel

I am using Excel 2013 to convert data from a spreadsheet into XML format by using an XML map.  The conversion works well, but Excel defaults all XML namespace prefixes in the output file to "ns1", as shown in the code below.

**XML to Excel Conversion**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ns1:CarrierInterface xmlns:ns1="http:/exampleurl.com/">
    <ns1:Sender>sender</ns1:Sender>
    <ns1:Receiver>receiver</ns1:Receiver>
    <ns1:RecordCount>1</ns1:RecordCount>
    <ns1:SequenceID>143</ns1:SequenceID>
    <ns1:Device>
        <ns1:ID>123456789</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Make>make</ns1:Make>
        <ns1:Model>model</ns1:Model>
        <ns1:ModelYear>2017</ns1:ModelYear>
        <ns1:DeviceWiFiType>True</ns1:DeviceWiFiType>
        <ns1:PairingState>Initial</ns1:PairingState>
    </ns1:Device>
</ns1:CarrierInterface>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <carrierInterface:CarrierInterface     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:carrierInterface="http:/exampleurl.com/" xsi:schemaLocation="http:/exampleurl.com/"> 
    <carrierInterface:Sender>sender</carrierInterface:Sender> 
    <carrierInterface:Receiver>receiver</carrierInterface:Receiver> 
    <carrierInterface:RecordCount>1</carrierInterface:RecordCount> 
    <carrierInterface:SequenceID>143</carrierInterface:SequenceID> 
    <carrierInterface:Device> 
       <carrierInterface:ID>123456789</carrierInterface:ICCID> 
       <carrierInterface:Make>make</carrierInterface:Make>  
       <carrierInterface:Model>model</carrierInterface:Model> 
       <carrierInterface:ModelYear>2017</carrierInterface:ModelYear> 
       <carrierInterface:DeviceWiFiType>True</carrierInterface:DeviceWiFiType> 
       <carrierInterface:PairingState>Initial</carrierInterface:PairingState> 
    </carrierInterface:Device> 
</carrierInterface:CarrierInterface>
```

Is anyone aware of an easy way to customize these namespace prefixes without having to write a macro?  Also, does anyone know why Excel drops the URLs given for CarrierInterface's namespace definition shown in the following lines?

**Desired Output**

```
<carrierInterface:CarrierInterface     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:carrierInterface="http:/exampleurl.com/" xsi:schemaLocation="http:/exampleurl.com/">
```

**Actual Output**

```
<ns1:CarrierInterface xmlns:ns1="http:/exampleurl.com/">
```

Answer (score 2):

Namespace prefix names themselves are insignificant; it is only through their binding to a namespace value that they derive meaning.

No conformant XML processor cares about the specific namespace prefix being used, and neither should you -- it's only the namespace value that matters.

Comment: @user2988717: I accept your apology for "living in a real World," but this answer applies to *this* real world.  If you have a question about some other world, please post a proper question, not a weak dig hidden in an poorly expressed query buried in an insolent comment.  Thank you.